# Google Cloud Run Deployment Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I just followed the google cloud run guide from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service) on Deploy to Cloud Run from source. But it shows the following error when executing the `gcloud run deploy`

`Deployment failed                                                                                                 ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'mybackend-00001-ctc' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

`index.js`:

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = process.env.NAME || 'World';
  res.send(`Hello ${name}!`);
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "description": "Simple hello world sample in Node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Google LLC",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Any thougts?

Comment: Update your question. Include the Dockerfile and deploy command. Review the Cloud Logs for your instance and include relevant entries in your question. I guess that your code is crashing during container startup. Tip: the contents of links change. Put details in your post so that we do not rely upon external sources.

Comment: Did you test the container in Docker on your local machine first? That is a good development and debugging method to use before deploying.

Comment: It's just the same example code provided in the link (Deploy to Cloud Run from source). package.json file and index.js file. No docker file.

Comment: You forgot to include the logs. It does not matter that you are using a document. The details must be in your question. When someone reads your question, the link might not even exist a year from now.

Comment: @sumedhe if my answer fixed your issue - I think it would be worth updating your Question Title and body to include the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the files you've provided leads to the following errors in the logs:

```
- /workspace/index.js:1
- import express from 'express';
- ^^^^^^
- SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

#### Solution 1) Add "type" : "module" in package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "description": "Simple hello world sample in Node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Google LLC",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "type" : "module"
}
```

#### Solution 2) Move from ES Module syntax to CommonJS syntax

Change from `import` to `require`:

```js
// import express from 'express';

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = process.env.NAME || 'World';
  res.send(`Hello ${name}!`);
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

#### Google Docs Bugged

Note - the files on the Google page are currently bugged. They've acknowledged this in the source repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/main/run/hello-broken

An updated sample is provided alongside it:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/main/run/helloworld